# RouteValueDictionary in a c# library project to support html extension helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0

I am trying to refactor a solution that includes 2 MVC projects: a "User-Experience" project and a corresponding "Content Management System project"

I have set up an independent  C# library -- "Services" -- project in the same solution space to do many things. I want to share Html extension methods used by both web projects by placing them in this "neutral" project so that there are no dependencies between the two MVC projects.

I have a problem with  using the RouteValueDictionary object (to.MergeAttributes) in this class library. I've included a reference to Sytem.Web.Routing in the Services project, but when I attempt to include a using statement at the top of the helper-class file, VStudio refuses to recognize the declaration ("Cannot resolve symbol 'Routing'").

This makes intuitive sense -- only a web project that can engage in URL routing should *need* a RouteValueDictionary.

But it appears common to use the RouteValueDictionary object inside htmlhelper classes because it can take an anonymous object consisting of name-value pairs and convert it to a Dictionary  in its constructor like this:

```
tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
```

...thus providing a way of passing in any number of tag attribute name-value pairs into a tag and a relatively simple syntax for calling the helper in the view:

```
<%:Html.SomeTag(Model.Id, new {@class = "myClass", title = "myTitle"} %>
```

So if I  can't use the RouteValueDictionary in my helper class, I'm forced with a more cumbersome syntax for my views, like this:

```
<%:Html.SomeTag(Model.Id, new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"class", "myClass"}, {"title", "myTitle} }%>
```

QUESTION: So, is there a way to re-write the helper class to get the simpler view syntax without using RouteValueDictionary, or is there a way to allow the use of RouteValueDictionary in a C# library project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What project target have you given your class? The only thing I can think of is that you have your project target set to `.NET 3.5 Client Profile` which doesn't support any web stuff.

**UPDATE**: Based on your comments, the final resolution was to add a reference to System.Web.dll to your project.

In .NET 4.0, the System.Web.Routing.dll is type-forwarded to System.Web.dll. This is because the functionality in System.Web.Routing.dll from .NET 3.5 was migrated to the core System.Web assembly. The System.Web.Routing.dll (v4.0) exists to satisfy type-forwarding (to maintain backwards compatibility when migrating projects).

When you add a reference to System.Web.Routing.dll to your .NET 4.0 project, you also need to add a reference to System.Web.dll.

Comment: ...and there's no problem with the other MVC classes used in this project like TagBuilder. Hmmm...

Comment: Ah, figured since you tagged it as asp.net-mvc-2 that it was MVC2 on .NET 3.5.

Comment: So, are you saying this just shouldn't be a problem as I've described it? It's fairly simple to replicate -- just start a c# library project, add the System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Routing references, and set up a test htmlextension class. Mind giving it a try and see if it works for you?

Comment: Have you added a reference to System.Web.dll?

Comment: no ... and that was it! I didn't understand that dependency. How is it that I could have already had a reference like System.Web.Mvc that does *not* depend on System.Web? Do they just set up the namespaces that way to confuse us??

Comment: In .NET 4.0 System.Web.Routing.dll is type-forwarded to System.Web.dll. The RouteValueDictionary in .NET 4.0 is actually in the System.Web.dll